# Picard's theorem - exercise

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $$R = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2\colon\, 0 \leq x \leq a ,\, -b \leq y \leq b \}$$
Determine the largest interval that gives the Picard theorem for the existence and uniqueness of the solution to the problem $$y' = 1 + y^2 ,\, y(0) = 0.$$
thank's.

The next question of this problem is : calculate the solution of the problem $$y' = 1+ y^2 ,\, y(0)=0$$
thank's

Answer (score 1):

Picard's theorem guarantees that the solution to
$$
\dot y=f(x,y)
$$ exists and unique if

- $f$ is continuous in $R$
- $f$ is Lipschits continuous in $y$

on $|t-t_0|\leq \inf (a,b/M)$, where 
$$
M=\sup_R \|f\|. 
$$

In your case $M=1+b^2$ for constant $b$. Since $a$ can be taken as $\infty$, you get
$$
|t-t_0|\leq \inf (\infty,b/(1+b^2))=b/(1+b^2).
$$

If you are interested in a solution with upper bound 1, then Theorem guarantees the existence and uniqueness of solution on $|t|\leq 1/2$.

Comment: Ok, so the interval is $[0,\dfrac{b}{1+b^2}]$ is it exact?

Comment: So the next question is: and calculate the solution of the probleme $$y' = 1 + y^2 , y(0)=0$$ my solution is $\int_0^y \dfrac{ds}{1+s^2} ds = \int_0^x ds$ then $\actan (y) = x$ but I am not able to deduct $y$

Comment: $y=\tan x\,\,\,$

Comment: but we can say this for $x \in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Plot $\tan$ and answer your own question.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the ode analytically, hints: its [separable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Examples_of_differential_equations#Separable_first-order_ordinary_differential_equations) and

$$\int\frac{1}{1+y^2}dy=\arctan(y).$$

Let me know if you'd like me to elaborate.

Comment: but the question is not to determine the solution is to find the largest interval given by the Picard theorem

Comment: I do this, and i found $arctan (y) = x$ my problem is to deduce $y$ on the interval given by Picard theorem